# Cannot get jabber clients to connect to ejabberd running on localhost

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I installed `ejabberd` on my linux mint kde. It installed correctly, I am able to use the admin interface in the browser at `http://localhost:5280/admin/` to add users. In the nodes menu it shows me one node running as `ejabberd@localhost`. There is a virtual host called `inspiron-n4050` which it created on its own. Now i registered 2 users from the admin interface `lovesh@inspiron-n4050` and `test@inspiron-n4050`. Now from my IM client(Kopete) i created 2 jabber accounts with jabberIds `lovesh@inspiron-n4050` and `test@inspiron-n4050`. But when i try to connect any of these it shows me error `Connection problem with jabber server inspiron-n4050. There was a connection error: Remote closed connection`

`ejabberd` is running because on the shell when i check `ejabberdctl status` it says

```
The node ejabberd@localhost is started with status: started
ejabberd 2.1.11 is running in that node
```

What is wrong?

Comment: after installing and browsing http://localhost:5280/admin, what is the default username and password you use to login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstalling ejabberd fixed the problem

Comment: any idea how to verify ejabberd with chat clients?

Comment: @Jayesh Jain: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup--mobile-6958 see `Testing the server` section

Answer (score 1):

I used this steps in pidgin xmpp. You can check out similar options on kopete.

1. Change proxy options to No Proxy
2. In Connection Security, Use encryption if available
3. Check allow plain text on unencrypted streams.

After this steps I am able to chat within two pidgin clients over a Intranet.

Comment: There were no proxy options in `kopete` but i enabled `SSL`. Plain text was already checked. But still i cant connect to the server

Comment: Well if you are on proxy (intranet or self-setup), Try pidgin client, As I have similar problems in empathy client on Ubuntu. But pidgin works fine.

Comment: I tried with pidgin. I entered username as `test` and domain as `inspiron-n4050` and other settings as you described in your answer but still it says unable to connect

Comment: Did you set connect server/port in pidgin.?

Comment: Yes domain connect server should be same as domain. Connect port is 5222 in my case as i did not enabled ssl.

Comment: i set the connect server to localhost and now it gives a message `Server does not use any supported authentication method`. I changed `SSL` to `Use encryption if available`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23691/discussion-between-lovesh-and-kuldeep-kamboj)

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that the there is a distinction between username "host" and actual hostname:
https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/messaging/instant-messaging-services-with-ejabberd-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin

i had to use these settings to get it to work:
username: username@localhost
hostname: www.theactualserver.com
port: 5222